# Parseval’s relation of Fourier transform

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis

The (Parseval’s relation) is
$$\int_{R^n}f(x)\bar{h}(x)=\int_{R^n}\hat{f}(x)\bar{\hat{h}}(x)$$

> But does the following relation hold:
>   $$\int_{R^n}f(x)h(x)=\int_{R^n}\hat{f}(x)\hat{h}(x)?$$

If I add another condition: 
If $h$ satisfies $-\Delta h(x)=L(x)$ where $\int L(x)dx=0$?

Comment: It does if $\hat h(x)\in\mathbb R$ for all $x$, but usually it doesn't (since the Fourier transform is not real a priori).

Comment: As far as I know, there is no connection connection between having mean $0$ and having a real Fourier transform. So no, there is no reason that your equality hold.

Comment: About 50 out of your last 60 posts are problem-statement questions. See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it does not in general. It is simple to see by substituting $h(x) = \bar g(x)$ in the first equation to get $$ \int f(x)g(x) = \int F(x) \bar K(x)  $$ where $ K(x) $ is fourier transform of $ \bar g(x)$, which is $ \bar G(-x)$ by property. Therefore, the second equation becomes
$$   \int f(x)g(x) = \int F(x)  G(-x) $$