# Is $\int \hat{g} h = \int g \check{h}$?

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis

Do we have $$\int \hat{g} h = \int g \check{h}?,$$
where $\hat{g}$ is the Fourier transform and $\check{h}$ is the inverse?

Comment: You're essentially asking whether the Fourier transform is unitary, which involves some choices of normalization and being careful about the growth conditions on $g$ and $h$ (even assuming they're defined on something like $\mathbb{R}^n$).

Comment: @anomaly What condition make sure this holds?

Comment: If you use the unitary normalization then this holds as is. If not, then there is a factor given by some power of $2\pi$ floating around. There are so many normalizations out there that it would be tedious for us to exhaustively list them, so it would be easiest for us to answer your question if you just made the normalization that you are actually using explicit.

Comment: @Ian I use this one: $\hat{g}(\xi)=(2\pi)^{-n/2}\int_{R^n} e^{-i\xi x} g(x)dx.$

Comment: That one is unitary, so your identity indeed holds.

Comment: @Ian Is it same as $\int \hat{h}\hat{g}=\int h g$?

Comment: Yes, as you can see by replacing $g$ in that identity with $\check{g}$.

Comment: @Ian But this is not right? See this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3616066/parseval-s-relation-of-fourier-transform

Comment: Sorry, you should be taking inner products everywhere, not simply multiplying and integrating. So one factor or the other should be conjugated on both sides (it doesn't really matter which, mathematicians generally prefer to conjugate the second factor). I am so used to doing inner products that this point slipped my mind.

Comment: @Ian Please the J.G.'s solution. Is it still right?

Comment: @BobOakley Now it is, but as you can see the argument of $g$ and $\check{h}$ isn't the same anymore, which is an artifact of the lack of the conjugation operation.

Comment: @Ian Do you mean $\int \hat{h} \hat{g}$ is non meaningful unless $\int \hat{h}\bar{ \hat{g}}$?

Comment: Not necessarily, depends what you are doing, but it won't be the same as the integral of just $hg$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your definitions,$$\begin{align}\int_{\Bbb R^n}\hat{g}(\xi)h(\xi)d\xi&=(2\pi)^{-n/2}\int_{(\Bbb R^n)^2}g(x)e^{-i\xi x}h(\xi)dxd\xi\\&=(2\pi)^{-n}\int_{(\Bbb R^n)^3}g(x)e^{-i\xi(x+y)}\check{h}(y)dxdyd\xi\\&=\int_{(\Bbb R^n)^2}g(x)\delta^{(n)}(x+y)\check{h}(y)dxdy\\&=\int_{\Bbb R^n}g(x)\check{h}(-x)dx.\end{align}$$

Comment: Do you mean this is still true although it is not the inner product?

Comment: @BobOakley Sorry; corrected.